# Hide/display div onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a script which hides an image and displays a text on the click of a button. However, I have similar buttons doing the same action in different divs. When I click the button the first button gets affected, no matter what button is pressed.

How do I manage to fix this?

Underneath is my JS. How do I make it so that the button only affects itself, and not just the first button?

```js
function hideText() { 
    
    const btn = document.querySelector('#info');
    const infoHide = document.querySelector('.info-hide');
    
    infoHide.style.display = "block"
    btn.style.display = 'none'
    setTimeout(()=>{btn.style.display = 'block'; infoHide.style.display= "none"}, 2000)
  }
```

```html
  <div>
  <button id="info" onClick="hideText()"> A button </button>
<div class="info-hide" style="display:none;">Copied!</div>
</div>
 <div>
  <button id="info" onClick="hideText()"> A button </button>
<div class="info-hide" style="display:none;">Copied!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: provide your html code so we can help you

Comment: share your HTML

Comment: a better approach would be to toggleClass, so that if it clicks it displays, and if its clicked again it can display none

Comment: Updated with HTML.

Comment: `id` attributes must be unique

Comment: `onClick="hideText(this)"` and `function hideText(button) {` allows you to access the clicked button

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed your event listener to be aware of the element that triggered the event. Actually that's not strictly an event listener but just a function that gets called when the event occurs.

There are better ways to deal with it using `.addEventListener`

```js
function hideText(target) {
  const infoHide = target.parentElement.querySelector('.info-hide');    
  infoHide.style.display = "block"
  target.style.display = 'none'
  setTimeout(() => {
    target.style.display = 'block';
    infoHide.style.display = "none";
  }, 2000)
}
```

```css
button{
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button id="info1" onClick="hideText(this);">A button</button>
  <div class="info-hide" style="display:none;">Copied!</div>
</div>
<div>
  <button id="info2" onClick="hideText(this);">A button</button>
  <div class="info-hide" style="display:none;">Copied!</div>
</div>
```

Anyway as another user pointed out in comments, the id attribute should be unique so I edited the answer to fulfill that condition.

And here I added the approach using a strategy not involving the event listener defined declaratively in the html:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{
  document.querySelectorAll('.smartbutton').forEach((btn)=>{
    btn.addEventListener('click', (event)=>{ hideText(event.target); });
  });
});

function hideText(target) {
  const infoHide = target.parentElement.querySelector('.info-hide');    
  infoHide.style.display = "block"
  target.style.display = 'none'
  setTimeout(() => {
    target.style.display = 'block';
    infoHide.style.display = "none";
  }, 2000)
}
```

```css
.smartbutton{
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.info-hide{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button id="info1" class="smartbutton">A button</button>
  <div class="info-hide">Copied!</div>
</div>
<div>
  <button id="info2" class="smartbutton">A button</button>
  <div class="info-hide">Copied!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: There you go! Thanks, Diegod.

Answer (score 1):

querySelector pulls the first element that matches your string. Thats why always first button and first info gets affected. You can provide button itself with `this` keyword and provide an id which determines the div to appear.

```js
function hideText(button, infoClassname) {

  const info = document.querySelector(`.${infoClassname}`);
  console.log(button)
  info.style.display = "block"
  button.style.display = 'none'

  setTimeout(() => {
    button.style.display = 'block';
    info.style.display = "none"
  }, 2000)
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button id="info" onClick="hideText(this, 'info-hide-1')"> A button </button>
  <div class="info-hide-1" style="display:none;">Copied!</div>
</div>
<div>
  <button id="info" onClick="hideText(this, 'info-hide-2')"> A button </button>
  <div class="info-hide-2" style="display:none;">Copied!</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

change your id in div from all 'info' to 'info1'/'info2'/'info3'/, and do same change in your js   const btn = document.querySelector('#info1');

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).